# How to create ansible master on GCP VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, configuration, ansible, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I tried to create ansible master on instance-1 in GCP. And I have an application instance-2. When I try to connect from instance-1 to instance-2 I always get error message - Permission denied (publickey).

I added instance-2 ssh public key to authorized_keys and configured parameter PasswordAuthentication to yes in sshd_config. In ansible file I have this:

```
 sba ansible_host=35.**.57.** ansible_user=admin 
 ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/admin/.ssh/app_gcp
```

Also I can't do sudo ssh-copy-id 35.111.57.111

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in wrong ansible_ssh_private_key_file. It should point on the id_rsa of the current machine.